# Cypress custom command for an array-like prevSubject

Tags: cypress

I'm writing a custom command `getFirst`, which returns the first element according to a given predicate. Everything works fine, but I wanted to specify a specific `prevSubject` parameter instead of `true`, in order to prevent improper usage.

In the [documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/custom-commands.html#Arguments), the only mentioned options are `false`, `true`, `optional`, `element`, `document` or `window`, but it doesn't say how to specify an array-like structure, like the [`cy.each`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/each.html) does.

Any idea how that could be done?

Here's my code:

```
Cypress.Commands.add('getFirst', {prevSubject: true},
<TSourceSubject, TPredicateSubject, TResult>(
    subject: TSourceSubject,
    getPredicateSubject : (sourceSubject : TSourceSubject) => Chainable<TPredicateSubject>,
    predicate: (predicateSubject: TPredicateSubject) => boolean) => {
cy.wrap(subject).each((item : TSourceSubject) => {
    getPredicateSubject(item).then<TPredicateSubject>((predicateSubject : any) => {
        if (predicate(predicateSubject)) {
            cy.wrap(item).as('getFirstItemAlias');
        }
    });
});

return cy.get('@getFirstItemAlias');
```

});

PS: If someone has an idea how to get rid of the `getFirstItemAlias` alias, or if there's some way to make its scope local, it would be very helpful too.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was curious so I looked at Cypress' source code to see how this was done.

There aren't any additional undocumented options for `prevSubject`: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/blob/develop/packages/driver/src/cy/ensures.coffee#L21-L39

`cy.each()` is using `{ prevSubject: true }` and explicitly checking that the `subject` is an array: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/blob/0f73bb7e1910296469f3f631a7f2303f4ecd035e/packages/driver/src/cy/commands/connectors.coffee#L374-L383